# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target in glassfish web service application

Tags: java, security, glassfish, ldap

I have developed an Java application that creates user accounts on a windows DC using ldaps which works fine after importing the self signed certificate from the windows server to my local keystore.

Now i have created a web service running on glassfish 4.0 and using the same code to create the accounts.

The problem is now the web service is now giving me the error below which i initially had but solved it by importing the certificate to my local keystore (cacerts)

```
Severe:   javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: 196.220.119.21:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:219)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2788)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
at engine.CreateStudent.<init>(CreateStudent.java:89)
at service.Create.createAccount(Create.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.glassfish.webservices.InstanceResolverImpl$1.invoke(InstanceResolverImpl.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:142)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:210)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:142)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:420)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:687)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:169)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:301)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:156)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:925)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:860)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1043)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:728)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:426)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:399)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:359)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:214)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    a
Severe:   t sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1351)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 91 more
   Info:   java.lang.NullPointerException

I have even tried to import the certificate into cacerts.jks and keystore.jks in the
    C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0\glassfish\domains\domain1\config
folder but to no avail.

I have also tried setting the keystore location in my code using 
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\security\cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");

Still no joy

Anything 'm missing that is important?
By the way i have both x32 and x64 bit of the jdk on my windows 8 machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why my application could not see my certificates was because of the setup i was suppose to do in GlassFish.

The GlassFish Server domain needs to be configured with the server's master
password to access the keystore and truststore used to initiate secure communications
using the SMTPS transport protocol.

1. Open the GlassFish Server Administration Console in a web browser at
   http://localhost:4848.
2. Expand Configurations, then expand server-config, then click JVM Settings.
3. Click the JVM Options tab, then click Add JVM Option and enter
   *-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=master-password*, replacing master-password
   with the keystore master password. The default master password is changeit.
   The async Example Application
   U sing A synchronous Method Invocation in Session Beans 36-5
4. Click Add JVM Option and enter
   *-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=master-password*, replacing master-password
   with the truststore master password. The default master password is changeit.
5. Click Save, then restart GlassFish Server.

Answer (score 1):

The glassfish container depends on its version, seems to have overridden your default JDK Keystore file to its own path.
**If other java apps in this machine work fine, the only issue is glassfish can't work, try this**

```
System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"); //add in servlet init()
```

This should run once when the servlet starts up, it will override glassfish Keystore with system default Keystore, which should work fine.

If your servlet doesn't have an init, add this into your startup servlet class:

```
@Override 
public void init() throws ServletException
{
    super.init();
    System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
}
```

If your JDK needs to work with this property, you need to set it in a different manner.

Why? 
Run this code in a normal environment (without any containers, just compile and run.)
Then run it inside of your servlet, with your Web App(Instead of system println, You can print the result on a sample webpage.)

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
```

You can see that with/without glassfish, results come out quite differently.
Result with glassfish:

```
/Users/jianqing/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
```

Result without glassfish:

```
null
```

Everything works fine again when it's set to null.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Glassfish looks at the cacerts.jks certificate file stored in the `GLASSFISH_SERVER\glassfish\domains\domain1\config` location.You can change this configuration or replace cacerts.jks file with your cacerts file.

There are some default JVM Options which Glassfish is used:

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:NewRatio=2
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-Xmx512m
-client
-javaagent:C:/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
-Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
```